# Warn of edit privileges missing before editing starts

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Would it be possible to warn the user he lacks edit privileges *before* he spends ten minutes improving a question just to see a nice "I can't let you do that, Dave" when he tries to submit?

Comment: Better yet, save the edit as suggested edit same way it's working in the site itself. And it's planned, though no ETA.